# How to prevent long running requests in an IIS worker process?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ektron

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see there were two requests open for a worker process for over 7 hours.

Is there a setting somewhere in IIS that can automatically kill requests over a certain duration? Clearly there is a bug on a page somewhere but as a stopgap we'd like to stop these requests from lasting this long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that if you have

> compilation debug="true"

in your web.config the timeout does not apply.

Comment: [MSDN agrees.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_0) (Scroll down a few rows or grep for `executionTimeout`.)

Comment: you just saved me! my whole app was stuck for 2 days. i checked every possible setting. till i came across your post. removing debug=true did the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a connection timeout limit in IIS configuration. You can do this by opening up IIS, navigating to configuration in the features view (at the correct scope, probably the website level), and setting the connection timeout property on the limits key. See the following article for more detailed instructions:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits

Comment: That's what I thought too but ours is set to 120 seconds in this case. It seems the Connection Time-out property only applies to _inactive_ connections. There must have been something going on with this connection. [see screenshot](http://imgur.com/Ral5Rjt)